# EC2 Server troubleshooting

Tags: mysql, html, apache, amazon-ec2

I have an instance running that points to an elastic IP. I also have the A record on GoDaddy pointing to that same elastic IP. I created a key, installed php, httpd, etc... through putty, gave ec2-user chown permissions in var/www/html and sub directories and plopped a simple index.html in that folder.

The problem is, I still get the 404 - so the site is completely unresponsive. I can nav into the site with WinSCP fine and the directories are all there. Is there something I am completely overlooking that is just an oversight on my part or do I have deeper issues?

Much thanks!

EDIT:

I did a simple service httpd status to check if Apache is running, and sure enough it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you recently updated the dns on GoDaddy it may just be that you have to wait for the dns to propagate to the right nameservers. Have you checked that you are getting a 404 from the right ip address?

Comment: yea - IP address and Public DNS time out.  With my other server, going to the IP would tell me Apache was installed on my server until I placed index.html there.  Do I maybe need an additional security group since I already have a server running?